# Trying to make a simple statistics report with google analytics based on events

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup my site with the new universal analytics from google analytics. I have included events when visitors do things. But it seems very hard to get reports about this event usage. For example, I want to know:

- What percentage of my visitors did something (for example trigger two events) in the last week?

I have tried to make this as a 'segment' filter in analytics, but it seems impossible. Does anyone know is this is possible in GA, and how?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the new Unified Segments? I know they are rolling it out across all accounts, but this would give you the ability to use the Advanced Sequences which allows you to segment your users and/or their visits according to sequential conditions.

Comment: In the segments I can for example select visitors that had more than 0 events at their visit. But it is unclear when these visits were, changing "days since last visit" does not seem to affect anything. Are there any other people who try to use analytics for reports like this or should I move to alternatives?